# Azure DevOps pipeline cannot find pipeline YAML file

Tags: github, azure-devops

When using Azure DevOps, there are times when the pipeline YAML file is not discovered and I'm unable to manually run a build.

In our case we only run automatically on commits to the `master` and `develop` branchesm, so it's expected that we run other branches manually. At this time we only have the pipeline YAML file in our `develop` branch.

Following these steps, Azure DevOps cannot find the pipeline YAML file and will not allow you to trigger a manual run.

1. Create a new called `test-branch`, branching from 'master'.
2. Delete `test-branch`.
3. Re-create `test-branch`, branching from `develop`.

I can now see that the pipeline YAML file exists for the branch in the repository. However, when I try to manually run that branch the 'Run' button is greyed out. When I try to edit the pipeline YAML file I'm presented with the following error -

> File azure-pipelines.yml not found in repository GitHubOrg/Repository at version/branch test-branch.

To be clear, the pipelie YAML file exists and runs on other branches. But it's almost like Azure DevOps is not properly pulling branch when I select to run/edit it, and I can't see any way to force that action.

I don't want to have to delete the pipeline from Azure DevOps because I'd lose my existing build history and have to update the associated deployment, but as it stands I can't see any other way.

Has anyone else experienced this behaviour and come up with a fix?

Comment: How's the result if you test in a new session of the browser? How's the result if you delete `azure-pipelines.yml` in `test-branch` and re-create one? Are you able to capture a fiddler trace when you edit the YAML file?

Comment: @CeceDong-MSFT - No change with a new session (laptop was off overnight). I've also tried going incognito, but no luck. In the end I updated the `readme` and committed that, and then Azure DevOps was able to find `azure-pipelines.yml`.

Comment: How often do you get this issue? Are you able to capture a fiddler trace for this issue?

Comment: @CeceDong-MSFT - I can reliably replicate the issue by following the steps outlined in the question. I'm unable to provide a Fiddler trace because my company prevents me from disabling their chosen proxy, so I'm unable to route traffic via Fiddler.

Comment: Weird that I'm not able to reproduce your issue, which YAML template do you select? I've tested with `Azure Repos Git`. Are you able to reproduce this issue on other client machine?

Comment: I get this error routinely and without a definite pattern. Just happens at random. I have to delete the pipeline and re-create it when this happens. The error is not helpful at all. Would be nice to get some details on what's really going on. In my case, the yml file is present and has not been modified in days, sometimes weeks or months. Annoying.

Comment: @DavidGard is this issue still happening?  I had this issue and solved it in my case but this may not help you much.  I noticed that the casing was different on one of the letters between the file and the configured yaml path in the pipeline.  So I just changed the casing of the file to match the pipeline expected full path.  One minor issue there was that I had to manually change it in the ADO GUI.  I changed it locally with git but it ignored the casing difference.

Answer (score 13):

In my case, I needed to change YAML file path in pipeline settings in order to find the correct YAML file.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

In my case, I was getting the `File azure-pipelines.yml not found in repository GitHubOrg/Repository at version/branch test-branch` because the service connection to GitHub for the solution in repostiory x had been deleted, apparently due to someone cleaning up what they thought were unused service connections (because I had created a bunch of svc connections needlessly).

The **solution** for my scenario which is admittedly slightly different from the initial question above but which also results with the same '...cannot find yml file..." error:

- **Create a new (in my case GitHub) service connection**.
  [image]

[image]

[image]

- **Go back to the build pipeline** and click the Edit button. Note, if you still get the YML not found error click the "Use default editor" to the right of the banner.
- **Select "Triggers"**, then Click on YAML. Now find your service connection in the drop down list to the right of the text "Authorize using connection" under the right pane titled "Select a source" and then click "Save" under the menu item "Save and queue".
- You should now be able to **run or edit a build the pipeline successfully**.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error and in my case someone rename .yaml scripts in repository but  didnt choose new .yaml name in pipeline setting.

Answer (score 0):

This error occurred when yml file is missing in the selected repo.

Answer (score 0):

When I created a pipeline on Azure DevOps the .yml file is committed to the  main branch. I was trying to run the pipeline on the code for the development branch. I had to merge main into development branch to get the .yml file in development and then push the development branch. This solve the issue, and I could run the pipeline with the development branch.